# How do I load the kernel for Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

When trying to boot my new computer I built, I am brought to the GNU Grub version 2.06 menu. When I try booting Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon 64-bit I get two errors saying: "unknown file system" and "You need to load the kernel first. I have been researching left and right on how to fix this an I can't find anything that isn't for a different version of Linux and has commands that don't work on my computer. If I'm being frank, I don't know much about booting up computers, and I'm trying to gain knowledge but it's confusing and nothing lines up, I'm hoping someone can teach me how to load a kernel for my specific version of Linux.

Comment: Did you install the normal way from an installation .iso, or did you try to do you own thing? There are requirements to where certain things should be, which kind of file system you need for the boot partition in certain hardware, and grub has to be configured correctly for the kind of installation you're doing. If you just wanted to install from the .iso, it sounds like something went wrong and I suggest reinstalling and following the default options unless you know what something means.

Comment: If you want to learn about the nuts and bolts of the installation process, you might want to look into installing something like Arch Linux or Arco Linux where they have documentation that takes you through partitioning the drive, installing file systems, configuration, etc.

Comment: Yes, I installed it from an .iso file. How would I reinstall it? Do I re-flash my USB drive or just re-plug it in? And thank you for the resource!

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing you did the first time. If it doesn't boot from the USB, go into your BIOS settings (often by pressing F12 shortly after restarting if the boot menu doesn't give you the option) and make sure the flash drive is the first boot option. If you don't know disk partitioning, just let the installer choose what to do.

Comment: I should have said, no you don't have to flash your USB drive again, unless you think there was a glitch with flashing it the first time.